# How to join the two Options<Vec<String>>

Tags: join, vector, rust

case 1.

```
v1 = None
v2 = Some(vec[..])
result = Some(vec[..])
```

case 2.

```
v1 = Some(vec[..])
v2 = None
result = Some(vec[..])
```

case 3.

```
v1 = Some(vec[..])
v2 = Some(vec[..])
result = Some(vec[..])
```

case 4.

```
v1 = None
v2 = None
result = None
```

Is there a generalized way to implement this?

Comment: While the answer from @EvilTak is really cool, I think the best way is a simple `match`.

Answer (score 4):

You can just use a **match** statement representing your cases:

```rust
let result = match (v1, v2) {
    (res@Some(_), None) => res,
    (None, res@Some(_)) => res,
    (Some(r1), Some(r2)) => Some(r1.into_iter().chain(r2).collect()),
    _ => None
};
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d0b3203b6bd865ef504e318555267a54)

Answer (score 3):

You can take advantage of the fact that [`Option`s can be converted to `Iterator`s](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#impl-IntoIterator) and use [`Iterator::reduce`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.reduce):

```
v1.into_iter()
    .chain(v2.into_iter())
    .reduce(|mut v1, mut v2| {
        v1.append(&mut v2);
        v1
    })
```

Chaining the two `Option` iterators will give us an iterator that yields either 0 (if both `v1` and `v2` were `None`), 1 (if either `v1` or `v2` was None), or 2 (if both `v1` and `v2` were not `None`) vectors. `Iterator::reduce` will only "reduce" the iterator with the closure if there are 2 or more vectors in the iterator and otherwise will return the only vector, if any, in the iterator.

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9bcb1f2581caf1b2d2275ba51f64cc63)

Comment: Note that you don't need the `.into_iter()` for `v2` - `.chain()` accepts an `IntoIterator.` Another way to do the same is `[v1, v2].into_iter().flatten().reduce(/* ... */)` and it is also extensible to more than just two options.

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=68db15a729a6c98fd0a6ddc1607478d7